# ActiveAdmin form on show page without a panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to add a form to the show page of a resource. The form works just fine, but it will only show up if I wrap it in a `panel` declaration, which results in a panel-within-a-panel.

Any idea how to get the form to show up without wrapping it in a `panel`?

Here's the code I have right now:

```
show do |ad|
    ...

    panel "Foobar" do
      semantic_form_for [:admin, resource, resource.reactions.build], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f|
        f.inputs "New Reaction" do
          f.input :title
          f.input :content
        end
        f.actions
      end
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to the `panel` would be to use a `div`.

The root issue is mixing Arbre and non-Arbre components; here those components are `panel` and the `semantic_form_for`. This alteration works because the last return value in an Arbre block is wrapped in a `text_node` when it is a String. In this case, the form is output as a string and then is wrapped as a `text_node` within the `div`, which renders the form. See Arbre's [`Element` source](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre/blob/98d91b4369a1ffff858c69bded3be43f85dc7835/lib/arbre/element.rb#L42-L45) for more info.

```
show do |ad|
  div do # <- Note the div
    semantic_form_for [:admin, resource, resource.reactions.build], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f|
      f.inputs "New Reaction" do
        f.input :title
        f.input :content
      end
      f.actions
    end
  end
end
```